# Как визуализировать данные через plotly или matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

есть код, возможно ли визуализировать это через график ?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
N = norm.cdf

def bs_call(S, K, T, r, vol):
    d1 = (np.log(S/K) + (r + 0.5*vol**2)*T) / (vol*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - vol * np.sqrt(T)
    return S * norm.cdf(d1) - np.exp(-r * T) * K * norm.cdf(d2)

def bs_vega(S, K, T, r, sigma):
    d1 = (np.log(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
    return S * norm.pdf(d1) * np.sqrt(T)

def find_vol(target_value, S, K, T, r, *args):
    MAX_ITERATIONS = 200
    PRECISION = 1.0e-5
    sigma = 0.5
    for i in range(0, MAX_ITERATIONS):
        price = bs_call(S, K, T, r, sigma)
        vega = bs_vega(S, K, T, r, sigma)
        diff = target_value - price  # our root
        if (abs(diff) < PRECISION):
            return sigma
        sigma = sigma + diff/vega # f(x) / f'(x)
    return sigma # value wasn't found, return best guess so far

S = 100
K = 100
T = 11
r = 0.01
vol = 0.25
```

Comment: через визуализируются данные, а не код, какие у вас данные получаются, и как вы хотите их визуализировать?

Comment: Вы хотя бы вызов этих функций покажите. Непонятно с какими параметрами в каком диапазоне вы вызов делаете. Чтобы был график, а не точка, нужен же диапазон. И `N` вы нигде не используете, непонятно, зачем оно присваивалось.